# Properties of ideals of a quadratic field

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Recently I read a book about number field, I learned that ideals of a ring $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ may not have the "unique prime ideal factorization" property for a quadratic field.

This is an example in an exercise for the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]=\{a+b\sqrt{-3}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Let $I$ be the ideal generated by $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-3}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$. The exercise wants to show that： 1. the ideal $(2)$ is not a product of prime ideals; 2. $I$ is the unique prime ideal containing $(2)$.

I can prove that $I$ is a prime ideal and $I^2=2I$. But other properties remains unproved. Could you help to provide some thoughts?

Comment: Any prime ideal containing $2$ will contain $(1+\sqrt{-3})^2$ and thus $1+\sqrt{-3}$. So $I$ is the only prime ideal containing $2$. It remains to check that $I\subsetneq (2)\subsetneq I^2$ to get that $(2)$ isn't a product of prime ideals.

Comment: Thanks to @renus. It seems that $I^2\subsetneq  (2) \subsetneq I$. But how this can lead to that $(2)$ is not a product of prime ideals?

Comment: $I$ is the only prime ideal containing $2 \implies $ if $(2)$ is a product of prime ideals then it is a power of $I$.